# How to auto scale Popup Window Android

Tags: android, popup, scale

Can someone help me. I have a popup window and how can i autoscale it for every resolution of android devices it must be in the center of my application?

This is my main.java

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

   int[] location = new int[2];
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);

   // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
   // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
   button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

   //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
   p = new Point();
   p.x = location[0];
   p.y = location[1];
}

// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
   int popupWidth = 230;
   int popupHeight = 300;



   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.


   // Clear the default translucent background


   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);



   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.filter);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
       popup.getContentView();
     }
   });
}
```

This is my popup_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/filter"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/CheckBox04"
android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
android:text="Filter" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:text="Test"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CheckBox01"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you heard about code indenting?

Comment: yes i know, i have changed it only for stackoverflow deleted the tabs

Comment: _deleted the tabs_ - and made it very difficult to read.  Please put the tabs back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you do android:gravity="center" for the layout of your pop-out window, it should center for all devices